# Using Worksheet_Change to clear contents due to change in specific cell, but not working

Tags: excel, vba

I want the following code to be activated when there is any change in cell C8. When a change occurs the ranges below should be cleared. It is almost working but for some reason the only time this code won't run is if I delete the content (meaning I go to the cell and press "Delete" on my keyboard). Is there a way to fix this and or cover this instance?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("C8").Address Then
        Resp = MsgBox("You are changing the job number. Doing so will clear your responses and the peer reviewer's responses." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "Are you sure you want to proceed" & vbCrLf & _
          "by clearing all those cells?", 36, "Please confirm !!!!")
    
        If Resp <> 6 Then
            'No was pressed, here's the message telling them action is cancelled
            MsgBox "No problem," & vbCrLf & _
              "please click OK, no harm no foul.", 48, "Action cancelled."  ' hello
    
        Else
    
           'Range("J26").ClearContents
           Range("C22:C85").ClearContents
           Range("C18:F18").Value = ""
           Range("C17:F17").Value = ""
           Range("C16:F16").Value = ""
           Range("C15:F15").Value = ""
           Range("C14:F14").Value = ""
           Range("C13:F13").Value = ""
           Range("C12:F12").Value = ""
           Range("C11:F11").Value = ""
           Range("C10:F10").Value = ""
           Range("C9:F9").Value = ""
           Range("C22:C85").ClearContents
                  
           MsgBox "Job Changed! Cleared Responses."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a compile error if you try `VBE debug -> Complile VBAproject` before running the code. There are two `If` clauses, but only one `End If` in your code.

*Fix:*

- Add `End If` at the end
- Using `EnableEvents = False` disables events before clearing cells so that the `Change` event is not triggered by itself.
- Clearing `C9:F28` can be done with a code line.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133240)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Resp
    If Target.Address = Range("C8").Address Then
        Resp = MsgBox("You are changing the job number. Doing so will clear your responses and the peer reviewer's responses." _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you want to proceed" & vbCrLf & _
            "by clearing all those cells?", 36, "Please confirm !!!!")
        If Resp <> 6 Then
            'No was pressed, here's the message telling them action is cancelled
            MsgBox "No problem," & vbCrLf & "please click OK, no harm no foul.", _
                48, "Action cancelled."  ' hello
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            'Range("J26").ClearContents
            Range("C9:F28").ClearContents
            Range("C22:C85").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            MsgBox "Job Changed! Cleared Responses."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried adding the Applciation.EnableEvents. code, but I didn't see a change. When I delete (Clear Contents) Cell C8, my code still not triggering

Comment: Have you tested my code?

Comment: Yes, but when I tried it with mine I am still getting the same issue?

Comment: If you haven't gotten any error with your code, I guess the code is in wrong module. Please make sure the code sits in the sheet module (Right click on sheet tab > View code > Paste the code). May I know what's result of my code? Is it same as your expected? If not, please let me know. I would suggest that you finish this testing first. Then you merge it and revise your code.

Comment: The result was correct, when I used the keyboard "Delete" button the code was triggered as expected. I will say in this private sub I have also case statement, but I would not know why this would cause the issue... I just want my code to run if someone were to use the "Delete" button on their keyboard...Your code does do that (I tried it in a different Worksheet)

Comment: I think your revised code works well now. It fixed the issure of "Delete" button.

Comment: I ended up needing to change -  If Target.Address = Range("C8").Address Then line of code to -  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C8")) Is Nothing Then - and this finally covered when I would press the Delete button :). Thank you again for taking the time to answer!